# Can we model Implied volatility using GARCH?

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, garch, variance

Can I use Implied volatility as a dependent variable in a GARCH model? I believe my IV data shows ARCH effects and hence can I use it to model volatility of the volatility? I know literature has used logged price differences in GARCH model, So I am a little confused If IV can be used or not (Since GARCH models historical volatility whereas IV is a forward looking measure)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you're going, but GARCH models usually have two equations: (1) an equation describing the conditional expectation of the dependent variable and (2) an equation describing the conditional variance of the error term in equation (1) as a process that is perfectly anticipated 1 period ahead.

When you use returns in equation (1), equation (2) is then used to filter out the condition volatility process from returns. If you say you want to model IV or its growth rate using GARCH, you're trying to model the volatility of IV.

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to allow for the volatility of implied volatility. So, can I use GARCH in that context? One concern I have is GARCH models describe conditional variance (P-measure), while IV is risk-neutral (Q-measure)

Comment: GARCH model describes conditional P-variance when applied to P processes. If you take IV to be Q-volatility, you are modeling Q-vol-of-vol with GARCH on IV. It doesn't miraculously become a P dynamics because you apply GARCH on it. We could quibble over how these measures will be polluted, but taken as it is you would be doing what you want to do.

Comment: So, just a follow-up question: Will the F-tests and T-tests still be valid if I use IV as the dependent variable. (modeling its volatility)

Comment: In a time series context, you can often obtain an asymptotic distribution for those tests statistics. Usually, that would be a chi square and normal law, respectively, because your estimator of the covariance matrix is going to converge (i.e., it's like it's known). In small samples, your scaled down Wald statistic is Fisher because your covariance matrix estimator is going to be random in finite sample -- and likewise for the t statistic and the Student distribution. The validity of those tests depend on whether you can reasonably make the assumptions you use when deriving their laws.

Comment: (Cont.'d) So, you have to ask the EXACT SAME questions you'd ask with any other regression.

Comment: There is a simple answer NO, implied volatility is an instaneous market estimation of the options forward movement in time, and hence, has to vary continuously over time, whereas GARCH is principally about taking heteroskedasticity or time variance from a model, the two are completely logically incompatible, it is like asking can I turn water to ice to see how far it spills, an oxymoron that makes no sense!

Comment: @nhoj GARCH doesn't magically measure conditional volatility under the P-measure -- it does, under some assumptions, if you use returns for the mean equation. If you look at IV, some aggregation of many of them on an index will behave like the VIX -- i.e., as a poor man's measure of conditional volatility under Q. If you apply GARCH on some aggregate of IV, you therefore get a cheap estimate of conditional vol of vol under Q.

Comment: Maybe you can take your condescending attitude elsewhere. IV at heart is just a dimension reduction gimmick: it's a convenient way to say cheap or expensive for options. I don't know where the hell you get "forward movement." VIX used to aggregate IV's. The newer formulation based on pricing variance swaps behaves very similarly and it gives you an estimate of Q volatility polluted by higher moments (Martin, 2017). So, my comment about vol of vol under Q do make sense.

Comment: @Stéphane Are you aware of any papers that do something like this? Many thanks.

Comment: @Raghav Goyal No. I am not aware of anyone who did this. I suspect something like this would be misbehaved, but then again I have no idea if it would be a cheap wat to proxy something more complicated.